# Weird JQuery scripts behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Applied DataTable (jquery.dataTables.min.js) to the existing table, so having that table paged and sorted:

```
$( '#news_table' ).DataTable( {
    "order": [[ 5, "asc" ]],
    "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 20],
} );
```

Everything works smoothly on first page of the table. Some JQuery scripts stop working correctly when change page. So, there are related chunks of code:

```
<td>
    <a href="#myModal" class="editNews" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-id="${news.id}">                         
        <img src="resources/img/edit.png"></img>
    </a>
</td>
```

By clicking on image (edit.png) modal window appears. The next part converts the modal to the edit flavour.

```
$( '.editNews' ).click(function(e) {                
    e.preventDefault();

    $( '#deleteNews' ).removeClass( 'notShow' );

    var dataId = $( this ).attr( 'data-id' );

    $( '#resetNews' ).addClass( 'notShow' );                

    $.ajax({                                 
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "admin/update/" + dataId,

        success: function( response ) {                     
            console.log( response );

            $( '#myModalLabel' ).html( "Edit post with id:<span style='color: rgb(255, 0, 0);'>" + response.id + "</span>" );

            $( '#newsId' ).text( response.id );
            $( '#incomingDate' ).text( response.incomingDate );
            $( '#changeDate' ).text( response.changeDate );
            $( '#messageTitle' ).val( response.title );

            $( 'div#messageStatus button' ).each(function( index ) {
                if ( response.messageStatus == index + 1) {
                    $( this ).addClass( 'active' );
                }                           
            });

            $( '.note-editable' ).html( response.message );
            $( '#messageOrder' ).text( response.messageOrder );

            $( '#myModal' ).modal( 'show' );
        },
        complete:function() {
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

I mean, that clicking, say on the link (edit.png) on any page excepting first one modal window will still appear, but will be empty, so looks like scripts just missed. I tried to figure it out, but stuck.

There are also some other scripts which also stopped acting properly.

Thanks for the any advice.

Images below illustrate the situation:

[image: Normal work on the first page]
[image: Second page]

Comment: Without dataTable everything works perfectly well.

Comment: What is your question? "stopped acting properly" is not a question.

Comment: I mean, that clicking, say on the link (edit.png) on any page excepting first one modal window will still appear, but will be empty, so looks like scripts just missed. I tried to figure it out, but stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this is quite common problem, you use your jQuery code once (on DOM ready I suppose).

When you click pagination table is generated again and that new elements are not bind to your jQuery code.

You have to 1) run jQuery code after each ajax request maybe using ajax complete:function() {//put me here...
or 2)
use jQuery "on"

```js
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".editNews", function() {
 //put your code here
});
```